# Ruby render partial on form submit on same page

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, render

I am trying to render a partial that I made on top of the current page after a form submit. This should happen in the controller's create method, but I can't seem to figure out if this can be done in Ruby, or if I should just render it using Javascript.

Here is what I have tried so far:

- Created a partial in the same folder as the new.html.erb (called _lightbox.html.erb)
- The controller render changed to this:

---

```
def create
 @user = User.new(params[:user])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      BackgroundJob.perform_async(@user.id)
      format.html { render :partial=>"lightbox", :layout=>false}
      format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

I have read up on render, however using the :partial key it simply renders the partial on a new page. I should probably just change the form to use :remote and add the lightbox-esque content with an ajax success, however I was curious as to if this can be done with Ruby on Rails with its rendering functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've displayed here isn't really the problem.  It's all in the view.

You need to prevent the default action from form submission, which is to post to the form URL.  If the browser posts to that URL, it will render the response.  Once you've prevented the default action, you'll then need to submit the form yourself using javascript and set up a callback to deal with the response.  That callback should put the html in the place you want it in the page.  If any parts of this are unclear, I can expand upon them.